# Reactor 3 create MonoEmpty from a map function

Tags: project-reactor

What should the return value in a `map` function be for the resulting mono to be `MonoEmpty`?

example:

```
Mono<Void> empty = Mono.just("ping").map(s-> ????);
```

or should the pattern be to do a `flatMap` if I need this functionality?

```
Mono<Void> empty = Mono.just("ping").flatMap(s-> Mono.empty());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a transformation to take place most of the time, but be empty on some condition, use `handle` (which has the capacity to map to nothing without the overhead of `flatMap`):

```
Mono<String> emptyIfNotPing = Mono.just("ping")
        .handle((t, sink) -> {
            if (t.equals("ping")) sink.next("pong");
            else sink.complete();
        });
```

If you *never* care about the elements and just want to propagate terminal signals (`onComplete` and `onError`), you can either use `ignoreElement` (which maintains the generic type) or `then()` (which turns into a `Mono<Void>`):

```
Mono<String> source = Mono.just("foo");
Mono<Void> emptyWithTypeLoss = source.then();
Mono<String> emptyWithoutTypeLoss = source.ignoreElement();
```